# Using absolute image position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an list of cliped image , each one has absoulate positon :

```
<img style='position:absolute;clip(xpx xpx xpx xpx);'/>
<img style='position:absolute;clip(xpx xpx xpx xpx);'/>
<img style='position:absolute;clip(xpx xpx xpx xpx);'/>
<img style='position:absolute;clip(xpx xpx xpx xpx);'/>
<img style='position:absolute;clip(xpx xpx xpx xpx);'/>
```

The problem here is that all of the images are in the same place , I want the go next to others .

I do absolute position because of Cliping image ;

what can I do ?

Comment: Please provide some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Seems like `float:left` might be a better option than `position:absolute`?

Comment: as I use clip on image , I can not use float

Answer (score 2):

Why you then position them absolutely?

To dynamically put them right after another, you need to wrap them into something that is not positioned absolutely. Like a relativ positioned list element

```
<ul>
   <li style="position:relative">
        <img src="" style="position:absolute" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

if you cannot wrap them, you would have to do it with javascript, something like this.

```
var memo = 0;
$("img").each(function() {
   $(this).css("left", memo+"px");
   memo += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

position absolute takes your element out of the flow of elements. Therefore your elements do not push each other around.

If you really have to use position absolute, you need to set the css property [left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) differently for each img. The standard value of top and left are 0. Therefore they are in the same place, or on top of each other.

Comment: yes  , exactly like what you say , I use absoulte as I use clip . do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try and set a left value for you images?

Answer (score 0):

Either use float: left, or set the left property of each image to be the sum of the widths of all previous images.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements must be positioned absolutely you can use the `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` selectors and adjust the `left: Xpx` accordingly.

- [MDN for :nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child)
- [MDN for :nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

Another option, since you're using inline styles, is to just stick a `left:` and/or `top:` value in to position it however you would like.

That said, it seems as though using `clip` is causing more problems than it's worth! There must be a way to get around that.